# web3.eth.getBlockNumber returns { [Function: get] request: [Function: bound]}

Tags: node.js, express, ethereum, web3js

I am using express and web3js, and when I try to get the blockNumber it returns

> { [Function: get] request: [Function: bound ] }

My code is:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

const Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();

web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'))

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    let Block =  web3.eth.getBlockNumber
    
    console.log(Block);
    res.send("It is me");
});
```

But I need the block number. How do I get it?

Answer (score 2):

Your could try using a callback as stated on the [docs](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethblocknumber):

```
web3.eth.getBlockNumber(function (error, result) {
  if(!error) {
    console.log(result);
    res.send("It is me");
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is about using `Block` variable as a function reference

`let Block =  web3.eth.getBlockNumber`

To get a result you should call a function either via `web3.eth.getBlockNumber()` or `Block()`

Please note that this function returns a `Promise<number>` and it should be awaited with `.then()` or `await`

Side note: web3 docs [suggest](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#getblocknumber) using `.then(res => { ... })` when another option is available - a callback as an argument `web3.eth.getBlockNumber((error, blockNumber) => { ... })`